How to encode HEVC with alpha without a Mac?
I am trying to produce a file that Safari on Apple devices will play with alpha support. I don't actually have any Apple devices, though, and all of the instructions I've found for doing this suggest that it can only be done on a Mac. But, I did some searching and reading, and it looks as though the latest version of the x265 command-line utility adds alpha support in software on any platform where it'll run.
Here's the process I've arrived at so far:

The video itself is being created using FFMPEG, using a filter chain that builds up an animated alpha layer and applies it, on a frame by frame basis, to another video.

I can get it to produce a suitable WebM file encoded with VP9. To do this, the tail of the command-line is: -c:v libvpx-vp9 output.webm
To produce an HEVC with alpha file, I have built version 4.0 of the x265 command-line utility from source code at https://bitbucket.org/multicoreware/x265_git, and then the tail of the FFMPEG command is changed to: -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuva420p output.yuva420p. This, of course, produces an absolutely massive uncompressed raw video file. :-)
Then I run this command to encode the video:
x265 --input-res 606x692 --fps 30000/1001 --alpha --crf 20 output.yuva420 output.hevc

Then I put this into a container using mkvmerge:
mkvmerge output.hevc -o output.mkv

For some reason, the timescale on this is all messed up. It thinks there are twice as many frames as there actually are, and it plays at 10FPS. I haven't figured out a fix for the first part, but the second part is fixed with:
ffmpeg -itsscale 0.3336666666 -i output.mkv -c copy -vtag hvc1 output.mp4

None of the tools I have seem capable of handling HEVC with alpha, so I don't know if this file actually has the proper alpha channel. I'm putting my trust in x265 with the --alpha flag. But, I asked a friend with a Mac to browse to my web site set to this file, and it didn't seem to work. They reported that the video seemed to be playing but nothing appeared. So, my assumption presently is that it didn't work. :-(
Does anybody see any obvious oversights in this process? How can I produce the file I need?
If anybody has tools to inspect the file and see whether it did, in fact, manage to encode with alpha information, the output of the above process is available here:
https://wizardsoftheplains.ca/Zap.mp4
